# My click event isn't being prevented in my (modified) foundation accordion

Tags: html, accordion, zurb-foundation

I have a modified foundation 4 accordion. The reason I've tweaked it is so I can have a row/column setup in my section header, and squeeze an extra column into it.

So instead of this:

```
<p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">Section 1</a></p>
```

I have something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-10 columns">
    <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">Modified HTML (uses div.row)</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="large-2 columns">
      <p>extra column</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem: The click event is not being prevented.

Heres the demo: (ive added the scrolldown to demonstrate the click on the a-tag jumping back to top.)

http://jsfiddle.net/pickledegg/nbJyu/4/

The javascript that prevents the click in a normal scenario is in foundation.section.js. Its combined into foundation.min for my example, so here is the actual un-minified code:

https://gist.github.com/pickledegg/5797197

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be because of this in the javascript

`content = $this.siblings(self.settings.content_selector),`

```
 if (!settings.deep_linking && content.length > 0) {
e.preventDefault();
}
```

The code above would be preventing the normal click behavior. However, in your modified code, you add 2 containers around the p with the title class. In order for the code to prevent the link followthrough, the p with the title class and the div with the content class must be siblings. Therefore, I'd probably just add a modified id to the html here:

```
p class="title" id="modified" data-section-title=""><a href="#">Modified HTML (uses div.row)</a></p>
```

and to the javascript:

```
    $('#modified').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
       });
```

Worked for me :)

Comment: thanks :) I'd actually figured it out and was coming back to update the post, but you beat me to it, thank you :)